# How do I restart Evolution's mail migration?

Tags: 11.10, evolution, migration

The Oneiric update on my mother's computer required a migration to a new email storage format on the first evolution start. Unfortunately, the migration crashed in the middle and only a small part of the old mails were correctly migrated.

I know there's a backup of the old mails and I would like to restart the migration process. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by deleting all Evolution settings.

First, make sure you have a backup copy of your user data from .local/share/evolution

Next, open Terminal and type:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/evolution/
```

This will delete all existing Evolution user data (like emails and address book).

Comment: This would remove the backup I'm trying to restore. I don't see how this could be helpful. Also, the 'sudo' doesn't make much sense here.